# Do companions drain fusion cores?

Tags: fallout-4

If I tell a companion to wear power armor, will they drain the fusion core?

If not, I could have the companion wear the armor to save energy when I'm walking places. When I get two suits, I can just have the companion wear the armor all the time.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**No, they do not.**

I tried putting a fresh 100 charge core in a suit, and telling Preston Garvey to get in. We then cleared a raider compound, and traveled back to town. I told him to get out and inspected the core. It was still fully charged.

Comment: I fully expect this to be patched though.  Having a team of Power Armor allies is probably a bit OP, considering how common they are.

Comment: @Nelson Highly doubt it, it's not like you can have more than one follower at a time. Besides, there's nothing OP about it anyway, fusion cores aren't exactly hard to come by.

Comment: @b1nary.atr0phy Well, in the beginning, it is quite difficult to get some of those. Also, they are drained extremely fast, at least in my opinion, which made me not using the power armor except in extremely difficult situations.

Comment: as a side note: Balancing in a Bethesda game is something which can be achieved by mods but by the majority of its players probably not wished :-)

Answer (score 4):

No, they don't use up fusion cores for Power Armor. I also experimented to see if this would work with the gatling laser, unfortunately it did not :(

Also something to be aware of, the armor does still take damage and can break.

Comment: You're saying that a companion with a gatling laser will eventually drain their armor's core? That's good to know.

Comment: Furthermore, companions just aren't very careful about preserving that armor.

Answer (score 1):

you can even take the power core OUT and they will still use the power armor. Ive got piper running about in full armor with NO CORE IN IT

Comment: Did you take the core out before or after they got in? Is she still moving at full speed? You can wear armor without a core as well, but you move slowly.

Answer (score 1):

I’ve had Nick Valentine in a suit for quite a while, and he doesn’t seem to need fusion cores. Not sure if it’s because he’s a synth, but on advice I have avoided equipping him with a Gatling gun of any kind.

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to add anything to the answer that is already accepted.

Answer (score -2):

Companions only require an initial jump start with a core, after that the armor runs off their charming personalities.

Answer (score -2):

I have a companion using a modified stealth set of power armor.  They won't go invisible without an FC, and I believe they will drain the FC when using the modification.

Comment: We generally try to do a little better than "I think so". If you wish to answer, do some tests for yourself, and post what you actually find to be the case.

Comment: That's something work checking. If you do run a test on it, let us know.