# Do settlers use fusion cores in Power Armours?

Tags: fallout-4

I read somewhere that settlers will enter a Power Armour if you leave them around with the fusion core in them.

It sounds like great roleplaying to collect all the power armours found throughout the commonwealth and let an entire settlement run around in power armours.

But do they need to be supplied with new Fusion cores?

This question is similar to [Do companions drain fusion cores?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/243222/do-companions-drain-fusion-cores) but not a duplicate as that question does not answer the behaviour of settlers, only companions which could be different. If that question is updated to include companions then I am happy to close this question.

Comment: Hi @Frank That question doesn't mention if the behaviour is the same for settlers as companions which is why I asked this question.

Comment: Oh, derp.  I missed the distinction between settlers and companions.

Comment: No worries, it might be the same behaviour but some behaviours, such as the use of ammo seems to be different. Cheers

Comment: Do we want to merge the two questions to a broadly more accessible "Do NPCs use fusion cores"?

Comment: @Timelord64 As the author of both the question and the answer on the other post, I'd prefer we didn't. It's nice and simple as-is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When NPCs use power armor, they will not deplete the fusion core's
>   battery charge. However, the armor parts will still take damage and
>   can eventually break, after which they will need to be repaired.
>
> Non-Companion NPCs will exit their power armor if the fusion core is
>   somehow removed from their inventory, which will allow the frame to be
>   stolen. This can be accomplished by either pickpocketing the fusion
>   core, or destroying it by shooting it.

Souce: Nukapedia, "[Power Armor Frame](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Power_armor_frame#Notes)" article

Based on that info, I believe the fusion core drain mechanic only applies to the player character, and does not apply to all NPCs, including settlers and companions.

Comment: +1, Probably true. Would be good if it was specifically tested for settlers.

Answer (score 0):

NPCs will only enter power armor if it has a Fusion Core, and they will only exit if the Fusion Core is removed from the Power Armor.

However, they will not drain the core during that time.